# On which page would I add an ajax query for ASP.NET web app with layout and partial views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I need to make my web app more responsive, such that data I have requested gets posted as it comes in. The problem is I have a web page, a layout page, and a partial page that contains a table. The table is the control being updated. (As a new test result comes in, it gets added on to the table for the user to view.)

If I wanted to use an ajax call for asynchronous data retrievals, which of the files do I update? The Layout, the main view page, or the partial view with the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is Asynchronous JavaScript Request from Client to Server. Meaning that you want to send a request from your JavaScript to your server.

The first part, i.e. making the request goes into your .js file. For example you may want to trigger the Ajax call on a button click... this button may be part of your MainPage, PartialView, Layout, etc... your client side logic goes into your .js file.

On the Server side, you need a controller Action to receive the request and send a response back.

[See this sample here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)